# Assign ansible vars based on AWS tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto

I'm trying to figure out a way to assign variables in Ansible based on tags I have in AWS.  I was experimenting with `ec2_remote_tags` but it's returning alot more information than I need.  It seems like there should be an easier way to do this and I'm just not thinking of it.

For example, if I have a tag called `function` that creates the `tag_function_api` group using dynamic inventory and I want to assign a variable `function` to the value `api`.  Any ideas on an efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you want to use this? What if you have instanceA with `function` tag set to `api` and instanceB with `function` set to `db`?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea and then using those variables to assign vars files.  We also have a tag set for `release` and `client` which can give us something like `prod` and `us1` etc.  So we could assign a file using something like `{{ function }}-{{ release }}-{{ client }}.yml`.  This is probably not the most AWS way to do it but we are stuck in other providers as well and hoping to have this work the same way we are already doing it with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make a dict of tags with lists of values:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - ec2_remote_facts:
        region: eu-west-1
      register: ec2_facts

    # get all possible tag names
    - set_fact: tags="{{ item.keys() }}"
      with_items: "{{ ec2_facts.instances | map(attribute='tags') | list }}"
      register: tmp_tags

    # get flattened list of tags (for some reason lookup() returns string, so we use with_)
    - assert: that=true
      with_flattened: "{{ tmp_tags.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tags') | list }}"
      register: tmp_tags

    # get unique tag names
    - set_fact: tags="{{ tmp_tags.results | map(attribute='item') | list | unique }}"

    - set_fact: my_tags="{{ {} }}"

    # get all possible values for a given tag
    - set_fact:
        my_tags: "{{ my_tags | combine( {''+item: ec2_facts.instances | map(attribute='tags.'+item) | select('defined') | list | unique}) }}"
      with_items: "{{ tags }}"

    - debug: var=my_tags
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ansible's `ec2.py` dynamic inventory script it makes all tags available as host variables in the form `ec2_tag_<tag name> = <tag value>`. It also adds all EC2 hosts to the group `ec2`.

So if your EC2 instance has a tag `AwesomeVariable = "Greatness"` and you want that value assigned to the Ansible host variable `stupendous` you can do this:

```
- name: Register variables based on tags
  set_fact:
    stupendous: "{{ ec2_tag_AwesomeVariable }}"
  when: "'ec2' in group_names"
```

After this runs you can use the variable `stupendous` for your EC2 hosts and it has the value set for the `AwesomeVariable` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this to work based on some more information I found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/ES2CjMPps3M

Here is the code that worked for us:

```
  - name: Retrieve all tags on an instance
    ec2_tag:
      region: '{{ ec2_region }}'
      resource: '{{ ec2_id }}'
      state: list
      aws_access_key: "{{ ANSIBLE_IAM_KEY }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ ANSIBLE_IAM_SECRET }}"
    register: ec2_facts

  - name: register variables based on tag
    set_fact:
      tt_function: "{{ ec2_facts.tags.Function }}"
      tt_release: "{{ ec2_facts.tags.Release }}"
      tt_client: "{{ ec2_facts.tags.Client }}"
```