# aws_ec2 inventory plugins: Creating host variables based on AWS tags

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Is there a way to create host variables based on the (AWS) tags on an instance? (without manually listing each variable and tag under the compose section)

The idea is basically to allow the equivalent of the INI-style inventory file using tags from AWS. (With the relevant variables using a prefix to identify them)

e.g. If an instance has these tags: (The array syntax is assumed from what works in the INI-style inventory and other options are acceptable)

```
ansible_swapfile_size=4G
ansible_extra_packages=["htop","iotop"]
```

I want these variables to be configured:

```
swapfile_size: 4G
extra_packages:
- htop
- iotop
```

`compose` seems to be capable of doing it if I list a fixed set of variables, but that means that if a new variable are added, the inventory would need to be edited. (There does not seem to be a way to use a loop to build the keys that is set)

Is there a way to dynamically generate variables based on tags (in the inventory)?

[This tries to do the same, but the solution require editing the playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39413088/1837991). I want the logic in the inventory - otherwise the playbook eventually ends up with a hack for every different inventory source.